# How to make your token safer without => setTaxFeePercent(uint256 taxFee) external onlyOwner()

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, tokens, security

if I understand correctly, this line allows the owner to adjust the fee afterward, so in the worst case, a rugpull is possible.

```
function setTaxFeePercent(uint256 taxFee) external onlyOwner() {
    _taxFee = taxFee;}
```

And if I understand it further correctly, this function serves as a protection mechanism, which is pretty two-sided.

I have read that there are better protections than how Safemoon does. How do I find out something like this, and what are they?

I'm just learning Solidity, and I'm very grateful for suggestions.

*(Edited because I forgot the hey)*

Answer (score 0):

Good question indeed, I think the best solution we have right now is Decentralized Autonomous Organization (DAO). These kind of changes should be managed by DAO through proposal based decision making.